# Método load possui beforeSend?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Gostaria de saber, se no método .load() do JQuery, possui algum jeito de usar o beforeSend, igual que a gente usa direto no $.ajax();

Teria?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://www.blablabla.com.br",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("body").html('<p>Carregando...</p>')
        },
        success: function(r){
            $("body").html(r);
        }
    });
});
```

Teria como fazer essa parte:

```
beforeSend: function(){
   $("body").html('<p>Carregando...</p>')
},
```

no método `load()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não.

O método [**`jQuery.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/), assim como o [**`jQuery.get()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), é uma simplificação de [**`jQuery.ajax()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

O que acontece no caso do `load()` é que a resposta do servidor será inserida dentro do elemento que for especificado no primeiro parâmetro quando a requisição for finalizada.

É possível ver no próprio código fonte da função.

Peguei apenas a parte principal da função (removi os comentários e formatei pra ficar mais fácil de ler).

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type || "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    data: params
}).done(function(responseText){
    response = arguments;

    self.html( selector ?
            jQuery( "<div>" ).append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :
            responseText );

}).always( callback && function( jqXHR, status ) {
    self.each( function() {
        callback.apply( this, response || [ jqXHR.responseText, status, jqXHR ] );
    });
});
```

<sup>[Veja o fonte completo no GitHub.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f18ca7bfe0f5e3184bf1ed55daf1668702c5577a/src/ajax/load.js#L16)</sup>

[Na documentação](http://api.jquery.com/load/), é possível ver que a função recebe três parâmetros:

- `url`: A URL para fazer a requisição;
- `data`: Objeto ou string para enviar ao servidor na requisição; e
- `complete`: Função de *callback* para ser executada quando a requisição for completa.

Se pretendes usar o `beforeSend` é melhor usar `jQuery.ajax()`.